# Emailing all users registered in firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to email all users registered in my db. The problem is, right now I have 12000 users registered.

This is my code so far. It worked for small numbers of users, but takes forever to run now. I also get this error `Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.` even though I set the memory to 2 GB. This is my code right now:

```
sendEmail.get('/:types/:message', cors(), async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(5);
    const types = JSON.parse(req.params.types);
    console.log('types', types);
    let recipients = [];
    let mails = [];
    if (types.includes('students')) {
        console.log(1);
        const tmpUsers = arrayFromObject(await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('student').equalTo(true).once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e)));
        recipients = recipients.concat(tmpUsers);
    }
    if (types.includes('solvers')) {
        console.log(2);
        let tmpUsers = arrayFromObject(await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('person').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e)));
        tmpUsers = tmpUsers.concat(arrayFromObject(await admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('company').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e))));
        recipients = recipients.concat(tmpUsers);
    }
    if (types.includes('test')) {
        console.log(3);
        mails.push('mail1', 'mail2', 'mail3', 'mail4');
    }
    const calls = [];
    console.log('recipients', recipients);
    if (recipients.length > 0) {
        recipients.forEach(rec => calls.push(admin.auth().getUser(rec.id).then(r => r).catch(e => console.log(5, e))));
    }
    const newMails = await Promise.all(calls).catch(e => console.log(e));
    console.log('newMails', newMails);
    mails = mails.concat(newMails);
    console.log('mails', mails);
    res.end();
});
```

Some explanation. There are 3 account types. There are students, persons and companies. Persons and companies are to be emailed at the same time, while sometimes I need to email only students. That's why I have this if stack.

For now I am trying to get all the emails from the db. How can I make this more efficient? And runable? Or even better, is there a built in Firebase method for this?

Comment: use pagination with limit in your request. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: If you want/have to work with large amount of data you want to use a streaming based approach instead of the collect and process all data at once approach you use right now. You might use a [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) in [Object Mode](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode)

Comment: Please remove the email accounts from your example...

Comment: @damienmarchand since I'd have to "cut" the database into chunks, is there a way to take the full length of the db? I'd be able to do some math then. Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: @t.niese This also looks interesting. Will look into it

Answer (score -1):

I would apply pagination with asynchronous callbacks in NodeJS. It's still going to take some time to accomplish but it can be done. Firebase doesn't allow returning in descending sorting but what you can do is something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('books').orderByChild('ups').limitToLast(2)
```

Then setup a Firebase function that performs the pagination and call that or just setup a new Firebase reference object and call that with something like Axios or Fetch API. This can of course be done within a NodeJS (server side) setting or client side setting. Here's a good tutorial on the subject:

https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-structures-pagination-96c16ffdb5ca